# Git GUI for novice programmer in single developer projects written in VB.NET with Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

What is a suitable Git GUI for a novice programmer in single developer projects written in VB.NET with Visual Studio?

I have learned to use Git through the command line but think that version-control could become faster and easier to overview if I had a GUI

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about software recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Source tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)**

By far the best git GUI tool today compared to all other tools.
Its free and all you need to to is simple register it.

But regarding GIt, CLI is still the best way to use it. Im using GUI tools for merging and diff only.